# Waiting for a file to load and a network request to finish

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, grand-central-dispatch, reloaddata

I have a UITabBarController with two ViewControllers that each display data. In the UITabBarController I load a 20MB JSON file from the bundle and make a network request. These both need to finish in order to display the data correctly in the TableView in each ViewControllers.
The way I did this (inside the UITabBarController) was by putting both tasks inside a `dispatch_group_async` block and using a `dispatch_group_notify` block to continue after both tasks are complete. I need a way to tell the TableViews in the ViewControllers that the data is ready and that they should reload their content (`tableView.reloadData()`). I was thinking about using the NSNotification center for this but I am not sure this would be the right way to do this.

Actually I would like some feedback on the whole approach. Is it sensible that I do these tasks inside the UITabBarController (since I need the data in both ViewControllers), and thus have to deal with "cross-class" problems? If you have any other suggestions please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I think `NSNotification` is a good way to do that. It's very clean and simple.

However to me the best place to load your data is into the `AppDelegate` even if it doesn't change much.